# onDelete() is not working properly in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I searched about this problem and i found one solution that is just change storage engine =  InnoDB,but my subsequent child's row still  dont get deleted.

My Models hierarchy is ....

```
Board -> Task -> Card -> [comments,files,labels];
```

If i delete task then all cards those are associated with that task should get deleted, but in my case, it doesn't happen.

Here I am giving you sample model of **Card**...

```
 if(!Schema::hasTable('cards')){
        Schema::create('cards', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('task_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('discription')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::table('cards', function($table) {            
            $table->foreign('task_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('tasks')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
            });
    }
```

Similar to all models I have implemented.So give me suggestion me to solve my problem.

Comment: You could move the constraint creation within the schema::create function, Laravel will run a second query for it anyway. Also make sure you're matching the datatype of the id on tasks, i.e. make sure it is unsigned (autoincrement keys usually aren't I think)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to add a constraint only when you create the table. But since you've added this line, it looks like the FK constraint wasn't added/modified since the table already exists:

```
if(!Schema::hasTable('cards')) {
```

Comment: So should i remove that?

Comment: The best way to handle this is to drop FK constraint and then delete the table in the `down()` method of the migration. Then run `php artisan migrate:rollback`. But if you need a quick solution, you could also just delete the table manually, rollback and run this migration again.

Comment: @DhruvKoshiyar no. In `down()` you drop FK with `$table->dropForeign(['task_id']);` and then delete the table. When you'll run `migrate:rollback`, the `down()` method will be executed and the table will be deleted. Then run `migrate` command and the table will be recreated and correct FK constraint will be added.